# Problema com Campos Mascarados

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Olá, estou usando o plugin `masked input` para mascarar alguns campos do tipo *decimal*!

No entanto, quando submeto ao formulário este campo chega como nulo na classe `controller`. Já procurei e não consegui encontrar nada a respeito.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Desde já Obrigado.

Segue o código.

Model

```
 [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
 public decimal? TELEFONE_FUN { get; set; }

Controller

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add_Funcionarios(FUNCIONARIOS funcionario)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //recupera o nome do usuario da sessao
                GRAgro.Models.USUARIOS usuario =        (GRAgro.Models.USUARIOS)Session["usuario"];
                string nome = User.Identity.Name;

                // seta o id do usuario vindo da sessao
                funcionario.ID_USU = UsuarioCont.PegaIdUsuarioLogado(nome);
                FuncionarioRep.Add_Funcionarios(funcionario);

                cadHistorico(historico, funcionario,"Cadastro do Funcionario(a):");
                TempData["Feedback_cadastro"] = "Funcionario "+funcionario.NOME_FUN+" Cadastrado com Sucesso!";
                return RedirectToAction("CadastradoComSucesso", "Feedback");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["teste"] = "nao cadastrado";
                return View();
            }
        }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TELEFONE_FUN)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TELEFONE_FUN, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TELEFONE_FUN)
                                </div>
```

Jquery

```
$("#TELEFONE_FUN").mask("(99) 99999-9999");
```

Comment: Se você remove o mask, ele chega corretamente?

Comment: Chega, por isso to intrigado, e quando no meu model o atributo é string ele tbm chega no controller normal, porém mascarado

Comment: Aonde você está esperando que ele chegue no model? não devia colocar uma propriedade no Action?

Comment: Ele chega na action do controlador nulo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, se entendi bem o "TELEFONE_FUN" está declarado no model como número, então quando vc passa o valor mascarado vai os parenteses e o hífen junto, aí da ruim. Tente "limpar" ele antes de enviar ou declare o campo "TELEFONE_FUN" de forma que possa receber esses caracteres.

Comment: eu tenho outro campo string cpf, quando debugo o código esse traz os parenteses e o hífen dai limpo e fica blz, porem esse decimal vem nulo não traz nada!

Comment: Certo, já tentou alterar esse campo telefone de decimal para string pra ver se funciona? De qualquer forma não entendi o motivo de usar tipo decimal para um telefone.

Comment: Um modelo string como vc fez no cpf pode receber o hifen, já o decimal não. Será que não é isso que está fazendo retornar nulo?

Comment: Criei o campo com string no model sem mapear pro banco, dai ele recebe de boa eu faço a conversao e insiro no banco Deu certo! Valeu gente